# Will Changing the file ownership of /var/www affect existing websites

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu, amazon-web-services

I have a site myexample.com hosted on aws using EC2 Ubuntu stack.
I installed wordpress and pointed blog.myexample.com to it.

The blog works fine except wordpress cannot write to the wp-uploads folder.
Error:

> Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads Is its parent directory writable by the server?

I have changed the permissions on the folders (777, 775) but it made no difference. It seems to be an ownership problem.
Amazon recommend doing this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/hosting-wordpress.html

Add the apache user to the www group.

```
[ec2-user wordpress]$ sudo usermod -a -G www apache
```

Change the file ownership of /var/www and its contents to the apache user.

```
[ec2-user wordpress]$ sudo chown -R apache /var/www
```

Change the group ownership of /var/www and its contents to the www group.

```
[ec2-user wordpress]$ sudo chgrp -R www /var/www
```

Change the directory permissions of /var/www and its subdirectories to add group write permissions and to set the group ID on future subdirectories.

```
[ec2-user wordpress]$ sudo chmod 2775 /var/www
[ec2-user wordpress]$ find /var/www -type d -exec sudo chmod 2775 {} +
```

Recursively change the file permissions of /var/www and its subdirectories to add group write permissions.

```
[ec2-user wordpress]$ find /var/www -type f -exec sudo chmod 0664 {} +
```

Is there a risk that I will affect the existing websites on this server? There are two.

Are there any risks to doing this?

I cannot afford to make a mistake and impact the existing sites. 
Thanks!

Comment: Secondly, this is off-topic for SO, it's not a coding / programming issue, it **MIGHT** be more appropriate for http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Careful. What you are suggesting probably won't affect existing sites, but it's not worth the risk. If you need to undo the change it's going to a whole lot more work.

Secondly allowing apache to write to all the folders and code on the server is a significant security risk. Anybody who gains access to your server code via a website hack will become the apache user and be able to re-write all your sites.

So. Just make the smallest change you need for Wordpress to work.
 Find the folder

```
wp-content
```

Then from inside the wp-content folder.

```
sudo mkdir uploads
sudo chown apache:www uploads
```

This will be enough to make Wordpress uploads work on your site without impacting anything else.

Comment: When I run 'sudo usermod -a -G www apache' to create the user, www, I get the error message "group 'www' does not exist". How do I add the group?

Comment: I took it from your question that www existed `chgrp -R www`. If it doesn't exist then it's irrelevant and you don't need to add it. You want to assign to the user:group that apache is using. Try `sudo chown apache:apache uploads`.